# Coquelicot library for basic undergraduate calculus

Tags: coq, real-number

I have installed [Coquelicot](http://coquelicot.saclay.inria.fr/) on top of mathcomp/SSreflect.

I want to perform very basic real analysis with it even if I still do not master standard Coq.

This is my first lemma :

```
Definition fsquare (x : R) : R := x ^ 2.
Lemma deriv_x2 : forall y, is_derive (fsquare) y (2 * y).
```

`is_derive f x0 f'` is a Coquelicot Prop that states that the derivative of function `f at x0 is f'`.

I have already proved this lemma thanks to `auto_derive` tactic provided by Coquelicot.

If I want to get my hands a bit dirty, this is my attempt without `auto_derive` :

```
Lemma deriv_x2 : forall y, is_derive (fsquare) y (2 * y).
Proof.
  move => y.
  unfold fsquare.
  evar_last.
  apply is_derive_pow.
  apply is_derive_id.
  simpl.
```

And now I am stuck with this pending judgement :

```
1 subgoal
y : R_AbsRing
______________________________________(1/1)
2 * one * (y * 1) = 2 * y
```

How do I solve it ?

**EDIT** :

if I call `ring`, I get :

```
Error: Tactic failure: not a valid ring equation.
```

if I unfold one, I get :

```
1 subgoal
y : R_AbsRing
______________________________________(1/1)
2 *
Ring.one
  (AbelianGroup.Pack R_AbsRing (Ring.class R_AbsRing) R_AbsRing)
  (Ring.class R_AbsRing) * (y * 1) = 2 * y
```

Comment: You probably want to look into the [ring tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual028.html).

Comment: @gallais : Thx. field tactic fails at this stage. I suppose I have to get rid of the term "one". I have tried unfold but it is not a good idea I am afraid.

Comment: Have you tried `ring`? You don't need the whole power of `field` here. What does `one` unfold to? I would indeed expect that it'd be a good idea to unfold it.

Comment: I have edited my question based on gallais's suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, it took me a little while to install ssreflect & Coquelicot and find the appropriate import statements but here we go.

The main point is that `one` is indeed just `R1` under the hood but `simpl` is not aggressive enough to reveal that: you need to use `compute` instead. Once you only have raw elements in `R` and variables, `ring` takes care of the goal.

```
Require Import Reals.
Require Import Coquelicot.Coquelicot.
Require Import mathcomp.ssreflect.ssreflect.

Definition fsquare (x : R) : R := x ^ 2.

Lemma deriv_x2 : forall y, is_derive (fsquare) y (2 * y).
Proof.
  move => y.
  unfold fsquare.
  evar_last.
  apply is_derive_pow.
  apply is_derive_id.
  compute.
  ring.
Qed.
```

Comment: OP already knows `auto_derive` but wanted to get their "hands a bit dirty". ;)

Comment: Thx for your efforts on installs & analysis. Appreciate it. Merci.

Comment: No bother, @FZed. I have been reading the new [SSReflect book](https://math-comp.github.io/mcb/) so now that I've found a good excuse to install everything, I might attempt to solve the exercises. :)